# Change EF Core query on the fly depending upon specific condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table called MainData

This table has a lot of fields but for the purpose of this question I will keep it simple

I have 3 columns

```
Name
Email Address
Id
```

So lets say

```
Name Paul
EmailAddress paul@paul.com
Id 1234232
```

Now I have another table called operator

```
Name
EmailAddress
OperatorId
```

With the following

```
Name Paul
Email Address paul@hello.com
Id 1234232
```

I have a service called OperatorService which has a property Called OperatorId which is a nullable long

What I need to do is when OperatorId is null I would get all the information from the MainData table which goes into my MainData object in my C# code

So

SELECT Name, EmailAddress, Id
FROM MainData

However, if OperatorId is NOT null I need to take Id from MainData but the name and email address from Operator for the OperatorId in the service.

I would like to do this in one place so that any access to the MainData entity in a query automatically applies this principle

Can this be done with EF Core Code First?  I'm currently on EF Core 3.1 but will soon be moving to .NET 7

Paul

Comment: Do you have a particular SQL query in mind? Other than that sounds like simple if with two different queries encapsulated into a method.

Comment: Or create a stored procedure and map it.

Comment: I didn’t think a stored procedure could be mapped in code first?